# Set MPI_ERRORS_RETURN before calling MPI_Init

Tags: mpi, singularity-container

I'm running into an MPI issue that I can't seem to find a resolution to here (or elsewhere), even though I assumed it'd be a duplicate.

On my local HPC, there is an issue when using [Singularity](https://sylabs.io/docs/) with OpenMPI. Unfortunately I don't have control over the fact that I have to use those two.

When I try to call `MPI_Init` in my containerized application, sometimes (maybe 2/5 jobs that I submit) I hit an error that looks like:

```
[<host>] PMIX ERROR: PMIX TEMPORARILY UNAVAILABLE in file ptl_tcp.c at line 688
[<host>] OPAL ERROR: Unreachable in file pmix2x_client.c at line 112
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

This is a known issue with Singularity, which usually indicates a mis-match between the MPI implementation inside and outside the container. Unfortunately I've checked that so that *doesn't* seem to be my issue. I've given up trying to get resolve the issue and now just want to mitigate.

I'd like to use `MPI_ERRORS_RETURN` instead of `MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL` so that I can abort my application more gracefully, but unfortunately I can't set that *before* calling `MPI_Init`.

Is there a way to get at this?